# sklearn OneHotEncoder wrong shape

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have an array

```
y_train: array([ 0,  0,  0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 0, ..., -1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

I did this:

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
y_train = enc.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(1,-1))
```

and the result came out to be

```
(0, 0)  1.0
(0, 1)  1.0
(0, 2)  1.0
(0, 3)  1.0
(0, 4)  1.0
(0, 5)  1.0
```

But what I really want is it to be onehot encoded like following:

```
[1,0,0]
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]
.....
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `toarray()` function after you apply the encoding to your `y_train` variable:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

y_train = np.array([0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
y_train = enc.fit_transform(y_train).toarray()
print(y_train)
```

And you will get this **output:**

```
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, any other ideas please? @Cardstdani